# Remove background color attribute from css onmouseover using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to remove background color of a div onmouseover.

```
$("#LoginTab").mouseover(function(){
    //Gives me white color
    $("#LoginTab").animate({backgroundColor: ''},1000); 
});
$("#LoginTab").mouseout(function(){
    $("#LoginTab").animate({'backgroundColor':'#babfde'},1000);
});
```

Here is the CSS

```
#LoginTab
{
    background-color:#babfde;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    opacity:1;
    border:#babfde 2px solid;
}
```

So the effect I want is that background color will be removed which will give me only border and stuff inside that div onmouseover

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: You cannot animate with the color property. There is Jqery Color UI something for it.

Comment: Any chance you want to accept an answer on this :-)

Answer (score 24):

You need to use `transparent`, empty string isn't a valid background color.

Also you could just do it with css using a `hover` flag:

```
#LoginTab:hover
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked :) Can you tell me if i can make opacity of background color to not fully transparent but something like 0.3?

Comment: Use `rgba` like this: `background: rgba(186, 191, 222, 0.3);`.

Comment: you can also using jqeury.color() plugin for change back ground color without using background-color: transparent;

Answer (score 6):

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/xjhBT/

you just need to tweak css, no need of script to do this

```
#LoginTab:hover
{
    background-color:transparent;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    opacity:1;
    border:#babfde 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just do it with CSS using a hover flag:

```
#LoginTab:hover
{
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using jQuery!

You can use `hover` jQuery function

> Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements. [[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)]

```
$('#LoginTab').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent' }, 100);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#babfde'}, 100);
    }
);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kHB6b/1/)

---

### Using CSS

You can do it simply with CSS transitions:

```
#LoginTab {
    background-color: #AD310B; /* <--- your color here */
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    height: 100px;
}
#LoginTab:hover {
     background-color: transparent;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kHB6b/)

### Setting the color opacity

In both cases you can use `rgba()`:

```
 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      ^  ^  ^   ^------ The opacity
 Red -┘  |  └----- Blue
         └ Green
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple way in jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#LoginTab").mouseouver(function() { 
           var p = $("#LoginTab").css("background-color", "none"); 
           p.hide(1500).show(1500); 
           p.queue(function() { 
                p.css("background-color", "#color"); 
           }); 
      }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

backgroundColor property can not be treated as other property in **animate()** function

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; **most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated** using basic jQuery functionality (For example, **width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the **jQuery.Color()*** plugin is used*). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable. **reference** http://api.jquery.com/animate/

for **jQuery.Color()** you have to download  **jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js** from [`https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">-->

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #LoginTab
        {
            background-color: #babfde;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            opacity: 1;
            border: #babfde 2px solid;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="LoginTab">
        login tab</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#LoginTab").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 1000); //gives me white color
        });
        $("#LoginTab").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#babfde' }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check This Fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/rakumoyal/n762fdg1/2/

As show in fiddle, You can do it by css ..No need to use jquery.

```
#LoginTab:hover
{
    background-color:transparent;        
}
```

It will work fine. Enjoy the code.